# Trying out AWS-Amplify -> "npm start" not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

To better know how to use `AWS-Amplify` I am following [this document](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?platform=purejs).

It all goes well, until I reach the point (*Step 4. Integrate AWS Resources*) where after modifying src/app.js I want to run this command:

```
$ npm start
```

and then hopefully look (in the browser) at:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

But here is what happens when running *npm start*

```
$ npm start

> amplify-js-app@1.0.0 start /Users/myaccount/amplify-js-app
> webpack && webpack-dev-server --mode development

Hash: xyzaghs789
Version: webpack 4.33.0
Time: 116ms
Built at: 06/10/2019 11:03:49 PM
         Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.html  1.55 KiB          [emitted]  
main.bundle.js  28.9 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = main.bundle.js
[./src/app.js] 145 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/app.js 26:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     });
| 
> 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! amplify-js-app@1.0.0 start: `webpack && webpack-dev-server --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the amplify-js-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
There is likely additional logging output above.
......
$
```

Since nothing is my own code here, only what I got from the document linked above.
I would guess other people have also hit the same issue at some point.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? (Which anyone knows of)

Just for reference, here is the contents of *./src/app.js*, copied from the link mentioned above:

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';

import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

// retrieve temporary AWS credentials and sign requests
Auth.configure(awsconfig);
// send analytics events to Amazon Pinpoint
Analytics.configure(awsconfig);

const AnalyticsResult = document.getElementById('AnalyticsResult');
const AnalyticsEventButton = document.getElementById('AnalyticsEventButton');
let EventsSent = 0;

AnaltyicsEventButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const { aws_mobile_analytics_app_region, aws_mobile_analytics_app_id } = awsconfig;

  Analytics.record('Amplify Tutorial Event')
    .then((event) => {
      const url = `https://${aws_mobile_analytics_app_region}.console.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/home/?region=${aws_mobile_analytics_app_region}#/apps/${aws_mobile_analytics_app_id}/analytics/events`;
      AnalyticsResult.innerHTML = '<p>Event Submitted. </p>';
      AnalyticsResult.innerHTML += '<p>Events sent: '+(++EventsSent)+'</p>';
      AnalyticsResult.innerHTML += '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">View Events on the Amazon Pinpoint Console</a>';
    });
```

Comment: Can you please update your post with the content of your `./src/app.js` file?

Comment: If you simply want to build a react app with aws-amplify, please follow https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react instead, it will work

Comment: I want to follow the document I mentioned in order to learn AWS-Amplify.

Comment: @David R. The content of ./src/app is nothing more than what I copied from the document I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I could add that to the post, but it would make it longer than necessary, since one can see the source (app.js) just by clicking on the link. I also just checked (confirmed) that I had made no mistake when copying.

Comment: I added the contents of the ./src/app.js file to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else happens to hit the same issue.
This (curly brace and paranthese):

`});`

is missing at the end of the ./src/app.js, file in the [document](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start?platform=purejs).